# parity of powers of prime factors

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, parity

lets consider the prime factorisation of a number N
let the powers of the primes in this factorisation be a,b,c ....and so on.
Is there a way to determine whether the number of powers that are even are greater than the odd ones or not.the factorisation is not known

Comment: I guess you assume the factorisation is **not** known? Otherwise you simply count.

Comment: yes its not known

Comment: I believe it's impossible to do this, for general numbers $N$, with any less effort than factoring the number anyway.